# UITableView wrong length

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uikit

I have a UITablevView in an UISplitViewController (which is in a UITabbarController).
My table is too long when I start in landscape orientation, so I set

```
 CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
    switch([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]) {
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            frame.size.height = 768-20-44;
            self.view.frame = frame;
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:           
            frame.size.height = 768-20-44;
            self.view.frame = frame;
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
            frame.size.height = 1024-20-44;
            self.view.frame = frame;
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            frame.size.height = 1024-20-44;
            self.view.frame = frame;
            break;
    }
```

this works.
But when my SearchDisplayController (has also the wrong length) hides, my tableview is too long again.
What can I do?

Comment: What version of iOS are you building for? And define exactly what you mean by "too long"

Comment: In all the cases you have same height, so why not one case? or even no case?

Comment: the table is larger than the screen, so I can scroll "outside" also some cells are not reachable.

Comment: And by "long" you mean the height of the table presumably?

Comment: Is your view controller a `UITableViewController` or a `UIViewController` with your own table added? If you are adding your own table, please post the code used to create the table view.

Comment: Yes the height.
Its a UITableViewController, in a UINavigationController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this code: https://github.com/alexth/TBSV , maybe it will help you. It's about how to mix UITableView, UINavigationController, UITabBar and UISplitViewController in one project with correct looking elements in both orientations.

Comment: I found my issue and the example put me in the right way. (I hide the tabbar but I have to do it before I do anything with the tabbar when I do it later it mess up the whole size calculation of the controller)